# What's the word for something that's shaped through a hole?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Scenario: I am pushing clay through a hole, and on the other side it is coming out as a cylinder.

What is the correct term to describe it coming out of that hole?

Comment: [Extrusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrusion)?

Comment: Yep, you've "extruded" the shape.  This is a very common and well-understood term in manufacturing and in trades (such as carpentry) which employ extruded shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments suggest, the process is "extrusion".

[**Extrusion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrusion) (from Wikipedia)

> Extrusion is a process used to create objects of a fixed cross-sectional profile. A material is pushed through a die of the desired cross-section. The two main advantages of this process over other manufacturing processes are its ability to create very complex cross-sections, and to work materials that are brittle, because the material only encounters compressive and shear stresses. It also forms parts with an excellent surface finish.